# Why adding content to divs mis-aligns them?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to place some divs side by side in a parent div which is itself contained in a parent div. Basically something like this (all children div need to have fixed widths).

```
HTML
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "wrapper1">
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
 ....other content
 </div>
</div>
```

Initially, I tried floating the children divs, but I also wanted to have the wrapper div set to horizontal scroll in case the children divs exceeded the width. With float they just wrapped to the next line. So i used white-space: nowrap on the wrapper div and set the children div to inline-block display. But the problem is that this only works when either all the children div have some content or all of them have no content, otherwise they misalign vertically. 
Working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/xj4pr7m8/16/

CSS code below:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.wrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child{
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Also, it does change anything if i add white-space: nowrap to either wrapper1 or wrapper or to both. Can someone please explain why the divs misalign based on content and what is a possible solution besides putting some placeholder text and setting it to transparent for the empty child div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing vertical-align property, set this to top, and you are good to go, you can also apply other values to the property acording to this

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.wrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child{
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "wrapper1">
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  ...other content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by adding `&nbsp;` to the empty div, and it will solve the issue. Granted it uses placeholder "text", but no extra CSS rules.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.child{
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
    <div class = "child">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, `&nbsp;` is still placeholder markup, even if it not placeholder "text".

Comment: @TylerH fixed it